# Unresolved external symbol LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, linker-errors, unresolved-external

First of all, I know this question is all over this site but I have looked at almost all of them and can't seem to find out what is wrong. This is in VS 2012. Thanks.

```
//Socket.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>

using namespace std;

const int STRLEN = 256;

class Socket
{
    protected:
        WSADATA wsaData;
        SOCKET mySocket;
        SOCKET myBackup;
        SOCKET acceptSocket;
        sockaddr_in myAddress;
    public:
        Socket();
        ~Socket();
        bool SendData( char* );
        bool RecvData( char*, int );
        void CloseConnection();
        void GetAndSendMessage();
};

class ServerSocket : public Socket
{
    public:
        void Listen();
        void Bind( int port );
        void StartHosting( int port );
};

class ClientSocket : public Socket
{
    public:
        void ConnectToServer( const char *ipAddress, int port );
};
```

Here's Socket.cpp

```
//Socket.cpp


#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Socket.h"


Socket::Socket()
{
    if( WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData ) != NO_ERROR )
    {
        cerr<<"Socket Initialization: Error with WSAStartup\n";
        system("pause");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(10);
    }

    //Create a socket
    mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP );

    if ( mySocket == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        cerr<<"Socket Initialization: Error creating socket"<<endl;
        system("pause");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(11);
    }

    myBackup = mySocket;
}

Socket::~Socket()
{
    WSACleanup();
}

bool Socket::SendData( char *buffer )
{
    send( mySocket, buffer, strlen( buffer ), 0 );
    return true;
}

bool Socket::RecvData( char *buffer, int size )
{
    int i = recv( mySocket, buffer, size, 0 );
    buffer[i] = '\0';
    return true;
}

void Socket::CloseConnection()
{
    //cout<<"CLOSE CONNECTION"<<endl;
    closesocket( mySocket );
    mySocket = myBackup;
}

void Socket::GetAndSendMessage()
{
    char message[STRLEN];
    cin.ignore();//without this, it gets the return char from the last cin and ignores the following one!
    cout<<"Send > ";
    cin.get( message, STRLEN );
    SendData( message );
}

void ServerSocket::StartHosting( int port )
{
     Bind( port );
     Listen();
}

void ServerSocket::Listen()
{
    //cout<<"LISTEN FOR CLIENT..."<<endl;

    if ( listen ( mySocket, 1 ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        cerr<<"ServerSocket: Error listening on socket\n";
        system("pause");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(15);
    }

    //cout<<"ACCEPT CONNECTION..."<<endl;

    acceptSocket = accept( myBackup, NULL, NULL );
    while ( acceptSocket == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        acceptSocket = accept( myBackup, NULL, NULL );
    }
    mySocket = acceptSocket;
}

void ServerSocket::Bind( int port )
{
    myAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "0.0.0.0" );
    myAddress.sin_port = htons( port );

    //cout<<"BIND TO PORT "<<port<<endl;

    if ( bind ( mySocket, (SOCKADDR*) &myAddress, sizeof( myAddress) ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        cerr<<"ServerSocket: Failed to connect\n";
        system("pause");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(14);
    }
}

void ClientSocket::ConnectToServer( const char *ipAddress, int port )
{
    myAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( ipAddress );
    myAddress.sin_port = htons( port );

    //cout<<"CONNECTED"<<endl;

    if ( connect( mySocket, (SOCKADDR*) &myAddress, sizeof( myAddress ) ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        cerr<<"ClientSocket: Failed to connect\n";
        system("pause");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(13);
    } 

}
```

And here's stdafx.h

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>

// C RunTime Header Files
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <tchar.h>


// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
#include "Socket.h"
```

And here are my error messages:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Client, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  Socket.cpp
1>  Client.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>Socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__accept@12 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ServerSocket::Listen(void)" (?Listen@ServerSocket@@QAEXXZ)
1>Socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__bind@12 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ServerSocket::Bind(int)" (?Bind@ServerSocket@@QAEXH@Z)
1>Socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__closesocket@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Socket::CloseConnection(void)" (?CloseConnection@Socket@@QAEXXZ)
1>Socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__connect@12 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ClientSocket::ConnectToServer(char const *,int)" (?ConnectToServer@ClientSocket@@QAEXPBDH@Z)
1>Socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__htons@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ServerSocket::Bind(int)" (?Bind@ServerSocket@@QAEXH@Z)
1>Socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__inet_addr@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ServerSocket::Bind(int)" (?Bind@ServerSocket@@QAEXH@Z)
1>Socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__listen@8 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ServerSocket::Listen(void)" (?Listen@ServerSocket@@QAEXXZ)
1>Socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__recv@16 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Socket::RecvData(char *,int)" (?RecvData@Socket@@QAE_NPADH@Z)
1>Socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__send@16 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Socket::SendData(char *)" (?SendData@Socket@@QAE_NPAD@Z)
1>Socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__socket@12 referenced in function "public: __thiscall Socket::Socket(void)" (??0Socket@@QAE@XZ)
1>Socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAStartup@8 referenced in function "public: __thiscall Socket::Socket(void)" (??0Socket@@QAE@XZ)
1>Socket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSACleanup@0 referenced in function "public: __thiscall Socket::Socket(void)" (??0Socket@@QAE@XZ)
1>C:\Users\ajayp_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Client\Debug\Client.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 12 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Did you add Ws2_32.lib to your additional dependencies part of your Linker/Input settings?

Comment: No... I'll try that and get back to this post

Comment: You can add it this way  - 
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

Comment: Ok thanks that fixed my problem. If you put that as an answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

The problem is you are not linking against the Ws2_32.lib library. To fix this you can add that to your additional dependencies tab of linker/Input settings for your project. Alternatively (as pointed out by SChepurin in the comments) you can add

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
```

to a source file of your project.

Comment: I facing same problem in Eclipse. How to Solve it?

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE. What is your compiler? Although if the compiler is not Visual Studio I probably can not help anyways.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520283/how-to-link-ws2-32-in-clion also helps if you're using CMake

Comment: @9Guy You deserve a medal for this comment.

Comment: @Spray'n'Pray I no longer have a clue what this question was about, or what brought me here. But I'm glad I could help haha

Answer (score 15):

Another way is that click right in your project in visual studio and go to following path and add "Ws2_32.lib" in that.
Linker>Input> Additional Dependencies

[image]

Comment: For someone who is not familiar with visual studio and C++, this answer helps a lot! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `runtimeobject.lib` to the linker *Additional Dependencies* (in the project property page, under *Linker*->*Input*).

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a linker error. the problem can also occur if you set wrong "***Runtime Library***" option in

**Properties > Configuration properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library**

both called binary and calling binary should have the same values

- if the property in the calling binary is **MTd**, then it should be **MTd**
  in called binary.
- if the property in the calling binary is **MDd**, then it should be **MDd** in called binary.