# fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fatal-error

.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


SOCKET socketOne, socketTwo;

int main()
{
socketOne = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
}
```

Trying to learn winsock socket programming, whatever you wanna call it, and this error pops up when I try to make a socket. Thanks in advance.

Also, this is the full error message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Hmwk.1.Assignment, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>hmwk.1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl loadBackground(class            std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int &,int *     const,int * const)" (?loadBackground@@YAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?    $allocator@D@2@@std@@AAHQAH2@Z) referenced in function _SDL_main
1>hmwk.1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl randomPlayer(int &,int     &,int &,int,int,int)" (?randomPlayer@@YAXAAH00HHH@Z) referenced in function _SDL_main
1>C:\Users\tmars_000\Desktop\Fall 2014\Intro to Game     Prog\Hmwk.1.Released\Debug\Hmwk.1.Assignment.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Did you link in the sockets library?

Comment: The full error message should show which function is missing. Then a search for that function on msdn will tell you what library you have to link with.

Comment: Possibly this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948064/unresolved-external-symbol-lnk2019/16948470#16948470