# POCO "unresolved External Symbol" Linker errors after updating SSL version

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, poco

I have been trying to upgrade my POCO libraries to 1.9.0 which required me to upgrade SSL, which has changed some library names. I am using SSL (OpenSSL-Win64-110g) from [Shining Light](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)

I was able to recompile the new poco-1.9.0 libraries , including recompiling the Crypto and Net_SSL_Open_SSL in vs2015 pointing to the new SSL (110g) version.

In my project I reference the newly compiled POCO libs and referenced the new SSL lib paths.

The new SSL seems to have replaced ssleay32MT.lib and libeay32MT.lib with libcrypto64MT.dll and libssl64MT.dll, respectively, so I changed those references in my project as well.

When I compile I get 36 LNK2001 "Unresolved External Symbol" Errors associated with Net, NetSSL, and Crypto libraries. (listed below).

I am wondering it either the SSL 110g lib is too new for POCO 1.9, or needs to be compiled with VS2015. Not Sure though. Any ideas on things to check?

Error list:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol GetAdaptersInfo   Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoFoundationmt.lib(Environment.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAStartup  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(Net.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAStartup  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_WSACleanup  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(Net.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_WSACleanup  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_htons   Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketAddress.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_ntohs   Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketAddress.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_ntohs   Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketAddressImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_ntohs   Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_ntohs   Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_addr.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_getservbyname   Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketAddress.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_accept  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_accept  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock2.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_bind    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_bind    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock2.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_closesocket     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_closesocket     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock2.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_connect     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_connect     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock2.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_ioctlsocket     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_ioctlsocket     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_getpeername     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_getsockname     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_getsockname     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_getsockopt  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_getsockopt  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_getsockopt  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock2.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_listen  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_listen  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock2.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_recv    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_recv    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(bss_sock.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_recvfrom    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_select  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_select  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(Socket.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_send    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_send    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(bss_sock.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_sendto  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_setsockopt  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_setsockopt  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock2.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_shutdown    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_socket  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_socket  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock2.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock2.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(SocketImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(Socket.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(bss_sock.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_gethostname     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(DNS.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_getaddrinfo     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(DNS.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_getaddrinfo     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(IPAddressImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_getaddrinfo     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_addr.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_freeaddrinfo    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(DNS.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_freeaddrinfo    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(IPAddressImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_freeaddrinfo    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_addr.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_getnameinfo     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(DNS.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_getnameinfo     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_addr.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __WSAFDIsSet  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(Socket.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_inet_addr   Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(IPAddressImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_ntohl   Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\PocoNetmt.lib(IPAddressImpl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _vsnprintf    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(cryptlib.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _vsnwprintf   Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(cryptlib.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __iob_func    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(eng_openssl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __iob_func    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(e_capi.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __iob_func    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(pem_lib.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __iob_func    Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(ui_openssl.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_gethostbyname   Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(b_sock.obj)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_WSASetLastError     Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\libcrypto64MT.lib(bss_sock.obj)
Error   LNK1120 36 unresolved externals  Server\trunk\Server\ide\windows\x64\Release\iqagent.exe
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved external symbol LNK2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948064/unresolved-external-symbol-lnk2019)

Answer (score 2):

OK so I figured it out. the Crypto errors were because the settings I made in the POCO project linker didn't save; I noticed when running the compiler that the output of the linker didn't include the new SSL libraries (libcrypto.lib, libssl.lib) etc. I also was linking to static libraries in Crypto and Net_SSL.

On the PocoNET errors, I had to include ws2_32.lib and iphlpapi.lib in my linker add'l lib dependancies. I haven't had to do this in the past.

I hope this helps someone in a similar circumstance.