# Linking gRPC on Windows for VisualC++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, grpc

I am trying to use gRPC in a Visual C++ project.

So far I have:

1) Build `gRPC` with `vcpkg`: `vcpkg install grpc:x64-windows`
2) Integrated the `vcpgk` libraries with visual studio: `vcpkg integrate install`

So far, so good - intellisense autocompletes the namespace etc.

My client `cpp` file looks like this:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <grpcpp\grpcpp.h>
#include "GRPCServerInterface.grpc.pb.h"
#include "FileFormat.pb.h"

using grpc::Channel;
using grpc::ClientContext;
using grpc::Status;
using namespace GRPCServerInterface;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    // prepare send message & payload
    IsFormatSupportedInput msg;
    msg.set_fileextension(".asp");

    // prepare reply
    IsFormatSupportedOutput rpl;

    // connect
    FileHandler::Stub ClientStub = FileHandler::Stub(grpc::CreateChannel("localhost:50051", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));

    ClientContext context;

    // execute rpc
    Status status = ClientStub.IsFormatSupported(&context, msg, &rpl);

    // handle result
    if (status.ok()) 
    {
        std::cout << "Format supported says:" << std::endl << "\t formats read: " << rpl.readsupportedformats() << std::endl << "\t formats write: " << rpl.writesupportedformats() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << status.error_code() << ": " << status.error_message() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

All messages & `proto` files exits and work in general, since I already use them in python and c# projects.

When building, Visual Studio generates a boatload of 125 errors, all in files I never touched.

In `GRPCServerInterface.pb.h`, there is `identifier GOOGLE_DCHECK is undefined`

All other errors are `member abc may not be initialized` in various header files in the grpc includes, for example
`member "google::protobuf::Any::kIndexInFileMessages" may not be initialized` in file `any.pb.h`. Many more in `type.pb.h` and `descriptor.pbp.h`.

Last but not least, I get prompted add `#iclude "pch.h"` to the auto-generated protobuf classes `grpcserverinterface.grpc.pb.cc` and `grpcserverinterface.pb.cc` - adding it changes a bit, but basically all errors are still `undefined symbol` and `member may not be initialized`. And I really do not want to modify auto-generated code every time.

What am I missing? Or is it just a fruitless endeavor to try using grpc with Visual Studio and should I just move to a build framework like bazel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it!

Two steps for solving:

1) I disabled precompiled headers for the whole project - this made the `#include "pch.h` go away. You could probalby get away with disabling it just for the protobuf files, as it can be done on a per-file basis.

2) One of the last errors listed was `unresolved external symbol __imp_WSASocketA`, which finally led me to this question [Unresolved external symbol LNK2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948064/unresolved-external-symbol-lnk2019/16948470). I just included `#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")` in one source file, and now everything works just perfect.

Comment: How did you solve the errors related to "may not be initialized"?

Comment: There's a bug report regarding the linker error: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/9840